# ùser mapping query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to know  how to get user mapping details in sql server 2005,whether the login user has the permission on the database or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sp_helplogins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190304.aspx) gives login + database mapping info